# Saxon XSLT .Net Transformation: What to give in BaseURI when xml and xsl both are passed as strings

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

This is the code I have for Saxon Transformation of XSLT files which accepts xml and xslt and returns a transformed string. I can have either xsl 1.0 or 2.0 get processed through this function.

`DocumentBuilder` requires a `BaseURI`, even if I don't have any file format. I have provided `"c:\\"` as the `BaseURI`, inspite I have nothing to do with this directory.

Is there any better way to achieve this thing or write this function?

```
public static string SaxonTransform(string xmlContent, string xsltContent)
{
    // Create a Processor instance.
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    // Load the source document into a DocumentBuilder
    DocumentBuilder builder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

    Uri sUri = new Uri("c:\\");

    // Now set the baseUri for the builder we created.
    builder.BaseUri = sUri;

    // Instantiating the Build method of the DocumentBuilder class will then
    // provide the proper XdmNode type for processing.
    XdmNode input = builder.Build(new StringReader(xmlContent));

    // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
    XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new StringReader(xsltContent)).Load();

    // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node.
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;


    StringWriter results = new StringWriter();

    // Create a serializer.
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    serializer.SetOutputWriter(results); 

        transformer.Run(serializer);

    return results.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that the base URI will never be used (because you never do anything that depends on the base URI) then the best strategy is to set a base URI that will be instantly recognizable if your assumption turns out to be wrong, for example "file:///dummy/base/uri".

Choose something that is a legal URI (C:\ is not).

Comment: Thanks Michael. 1 more thing. Is it ok to create custom xslt 2.0 specific function within xslt 1.0 doc and process it with saxon?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. It's worth reading up on how an XSLT 1.0 processor handles code marked as version="2.0" (forwards-compatible mode), and how an XSLT 2.0 processor handles code marked as version="1.0" (backwards compatible mode).

Comment: Can you please provide some links for that? Also, if I am having xslt version 1.0 stylesheet but transforming through a 2.0 processor like Saxon, can I completely remove node-set() function references? Is it not required by Saxon?

Comment: For references on forwards/backwards compatibility, either read the W3C specs, or read my book XSLT 2.0 Programmers Reference. Re exlst:node-set(), yes, this is not needed in 2.0.